# SearcherManager maybeRefresh method not happening

Tags: java, lucene

I'm using Lucene 4.0 API in order to implement search in my application.

The navigation flow is as follows:

1. The user creates a new article. A new `Document` is than added to the index using `IndexWriter.addDocument()`.
2. After addition the `SearcherManager.maybeRefresh()` method is called. The `SearcherManager` is built from the `Writer` in order to have access to NRL Search.
3. Just after the creation, the user decides to add a new tag to his article. This is when the  `Writer.updateDocument()` is called. Considering that at step 2 I asked for a refresh I would expect the Searcher to find the added document. However, this is not found.

Is this the common behaviour? Is there a way to make shore that the Searcher finds the Document? (except commit)

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that your newly created document is kept in the memory. Lucene doesn't make the changes immediately, it keeps some documents in memory, because the I/O operations take some time and resources. It is a good practice to write only once the buffer is full. But, since you would like to view and change the document immediately, try flushing the buffer first(`IndexWriter.flush()`). This should write to disk. Only **after** this try (maybe)refreshing.

Comment: I would like to avoid using `.flush()`. Considering that I'm using the NRT Search I don't think that this is necessary.